# Drupal lost settings and public files when pushing to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: git, drupal, amazon-web-services, drupal-7, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Every time I update my drupal website to AWS Elastic Beanstalk all files that were uploaded to public folder are lost. Worst yet, settings are also lost; I need to configure database settings again.

For instance: I made a change to my theme style.css, then I push:

git add sites/all/themes/theme_name/style.css

git commit -m "new styles"

git aws.push

After AWS deploy the website and I visit any page, it shows installation screen and I have to configure database settings again. If an image was uploaded to public folder,that image is gone.

.gitignore is there and it has the lines to exclude sites folder.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Just to clear out, do you have the problem that you move the settings.php via FTP and it's removed at deployment (or removed even when created)?

In your .gitignore, do you have something like:

```
sites/*/settings*.php
sites/*/files
sites/*/private
```

If yes, the behavior is natural. Any settings*.php will never be moved on the server since it's ignored. To avoid this, put a # - comment out the line like:

```
# sites/*/settings*.php
```

Similar to each line that you want to ignore. Usually these files are not moved since they are server specific.

As you change the gitignore, I've mentioned that to take effect of the changes you have to push first to the master - origin of the git repository.

If you don't want to update each time your settings.php file, I've wrote on my blog site a switch that handles the server URL for applying the correct settings. You can find further info [here](http://frizi.net/drupal-server/drupal-multiple-web-platforms-and-settings-file-protection).

As last, files folder shouldn't be pushed via Git!!! these are to big for the transfer and should be moved via FTP.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Frizi. Here are my comments:

Comment: **1** I'm not uploading via FTP. I'm using GIT

Comment: **2** I'm not uploading settings.php, it is already on server. It should remains the same (that's what I want)

Comment: **3** Yes, .gitignore looks like that. So, it should ignore settings.php and files folder

Comment: **4** I'm not uploading files folder. However, once AWS deploys, all files on Files folder are gone

Answer (score -3):

I was having the same issue and found this post - http://damontorgerson.com/aws/drupal/elastic-beanstalk-drupal-settings/

So you need to fill out the items in the php environment container and add the suggested file from Damon's post and also add to the bottom of your settings file.

Here is a AWS doc that shows how to set up the parameters.  It is for java but it still applies for php.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.managing.html

Mark

Comment: Link is broken. Resolution should be detailed here rather than point to a blog post.